# how do I add padding to each element of a list?

Tags: css

I'm trying to add padding above and below each element of a list. Here is my current code:

```html
<html>

<head>Basic Report</head>

<body>
    <p>
        A<br>
        <ul>
            <li class="pad">B</li>
            <li class="pad">C</li>
            <li class="pad">D</li>
            <li class="pad">E</li>
            <li class="pad">F</li>
            <li class="pad">G</li>
            <li class="pad">H</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</body>

</html>
```

This is my css:

```css
p{
    font-size:14;
}
* {
    font-family: Calibri;
}
.pad {
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

Two questions:

1. The padding isn't working. Why is that?
2. Is there any way to add padding to all the elements with one bit of code? Or do I need to add class="pad" to each list item?

I'm a total noob at html and css btw. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Is the CSS in another file like `mystyle.css` ?

Comment: an ul cannot be a child of a p (paragraph) use a div instead so it can hold any block level tags.

Comment: @G-Cyrillus: According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/ul), the permitted partents of a `ul`  are `Any element that accepts flow content.`... And `p` is one of them.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette  hmm , i thought it was only about phrasing content. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p it says it is flow content but also Permitted content is phrasing content . You can omit the closing tag if followed by a few tags (including ul) ... My english has its limits here , ;)

Comment: I tested it and effectively, like Kartik Malik mentionned below *"Interpreter will break the <p> tag automatically right before <ul> and start another <p> tag after <ul/>"* - ;) - But while super interesting, that is beyond the scope of the original question.

Answer (score 0):

1. There isn't any problem with your code. I recommend you select all
   of the li tags just like this `li {}` instead of giving each of
   them a class. you can also use padding-block for top and bottom and
   padding-inline for right and left.
2. The reason why you can't see the padding might be that you haven't linked the right file or referenced the wrong address. Cause I copy pasted your code and it was working for me.

```css
p {
  font-size: 14;
}

* {
  font-family: Calibri;
}

li {
  /* padding-top: 50px;
  padding-bottom: 10px; */
  padding: 50px 0 10px 0;
  /* you can also use padding-block for top and bottom and padding-inline for right and left */
}
```

```html
<p>
  A<br>
  <ul>
    <li>B</li>
    <li>C</li>
    <li>D</li>
    <li>E</li>
    <li>F</li>
    <li>G</li>
    <li>H</li>
  </ul>
</p>
```

Comment: a `<p>` parent of an `<ul>` is sort of a problem :)

Comment: Don't tell me, tell him this is his code not mine.

Comment: Conventionally its is incorrect, but technically it won't be a problem. Interpreter will break the <p> tag automatically right before <ul> and start another <p> tag after <ul/>. :)

Comment: actually, not too sure when you read again :  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p

Comment: @KartikMalik yep, like the tbody always added if missing, the only thing about browser fixing errors is that sometimes it messes up how CSS can be applied from a browser to another . A clean HTML avoids funny CSS rendering and chasing for a bug that might not be one.

Comment: As @KartikMalik said, yes I also think that there won't be a technical problem but as everyone knows, it's not standard and common.

Comment: However, advising to mind also the HTML structure for a beginner should not be a trouble :)

Comment: We have conventions/best practices for a reason :D

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct and padding should work maybe your CSS file is not linked properly.

an easier method of doing what you want to do is you can give a class to its parent and do it as I did in the code below.

```css
.list li{
  padding-top:50px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>
        A<br>
        <ul class="list">
            <li>B</li>
            <li>C</li>
            <li>D</li>
            <li>E</li>
            <li>F</li>
            <li>G</li>
            <li>H</li>
        </ul>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: a `<p>` parent of an `<ul>` is not really *correct* :)

Comment: Conventionally its is incorrect, but technically it won't be a problem. Interpreter will break the <p> tag automatically right before <ul> and start another <p> tag after <ul/>. :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no style difinition in the posted HTML markup. So I assume the CSS is in another file. You have to link it.

And by the way, `<head>Basic Report</head>` is not valid... It probably should be:

```
<head>
  <title>Basic Report</title>
</head>
```

And then, you can add a link to the CSS file:

```
<head>
  <title>Basic Report</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="mystyle.css">
</head>
```

> do I need to add class="pad" to each list item?

You could do:

```
li{
  padding-top:50px;
  padding-bottom:10px;
}
```

to avoid the class addition in the HTML markup...

Answer (score 0):

there is no problem with the padding it works, you can directly target the tag

CSS code:

```css
*{
    font-family: Calibri;
}

p{
    font-size:14;
}

li {
    padding-top:50px;
    padding-bottom:10px;
}
```